# How to save changes data in CKEditor after submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, ckeditor

I'm using JSP and CKEditor to get website's content

```
<form method="POST">    
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor">DEMO CKEDITOR</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes">

    <div id="content" ></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
    </script>
</form>
```

The contents of the website are saved in div "content". How can I load them into CKEditor to edit and save changes?. After submit form, the website will display new content.